# Constructor in C++

Tags: c++, composition, initializer-list

My question is that: 
for example I have two classes x and y

```
class X{
public:
      X(int, int, string);

private: int a;
         int b;
         string c;
};

class Y{

private: X x[10];
}
```

My question is that how to initialize this array of 10 x objects through constructor of Y? Initializer list? How to initialize these 10 objects of x in y.

Comment: are you asking really about this or how in general to do it? you might use vector instead of raw array i.e.

Comment: Lets say the size is fixed i.e. 10, and even If I use vector I will have to initialize all 10 objects?

Comment: do you need 10 objects specified one by one? or 10 exactly same objects?

Comment: For each Y I create I need 10 different objects of type x in array of size 10.

Comment: you can have a vector and do push_back in constructor

Comment: @computer: That ruins locality of reference, among other problems.

Comment: I know this is not the best approach, however this is possible solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++03 you cannot do this.

In C++11, like this:

```
class Y
{
private:
    X x[3];
public:
    Y()
    : x { X(1, 2, "a"), X(2, 3, "b"), X(3, 4, "c") }
    {
    }
};
```

Alternatively you can say:

```
    : x { {1, 2, "a"}, {2, 3, "b"}, {3, 4, "c"} }
```

Comment: `std::array` and a helper function make it possible in C++03 also, don't they?

Comment: @BenVoigt `<array>` is C++11 header, isn't it?

Comment: @VeriTi: You're right, so you'd need to provide your own aggregate instead.

Comment: But there is `placement new` in C++03

Comment: for example, http://ideone.com/dmo80F  (Add `operator[]` or `operator T*()` to make it useful)

Comment: @FarazAhmad: [Works fine for me](http://ideone.com/DPquls)... are you sure you have a C++11 compiler?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, `std::tr1::array<X, 10>` should be a fine and widely available solution. I figured the OP has a reason to use raw arrays; otherwise I'd always prefer the class-based solution...

Comment: And what is the class based solution? Thanks

Comment: @FarazAhmad: To use a class that wraps the array, such as `std::array` or `std::tr1::array`. That said, without brace initializer syntax you also can't do aggregate initialization in initializer lists, so I take it back, that wouldn't help.

Comment: I linked an example of initializing (not assigning) an aggregate class member in my previous comment.

Comment: @FarazAhmad: VS2012 supports only pieces of C++11, and uniform initializer syntax isn't one of them.